# Issue with shiny reactivity

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I try to display the number of lines that matchs selecinput criteria with a possibility to add comment.
Everytime someone add a comment, it s add a line, and i would like to update the number of line.
(Actually i am working on a comment section where I want to display all the comments from a player and display every new comment submitted)

For the output$texte, when the selectinput changes, the df is subset, so the reactive works. When i have an observeEvent, df is saved, but there is no reactivity. when I switch the selected players, it never take into account the change in df, it's like he imports df once and never update it for the display.

Thanks for your help

```
df<-data.frame(nom=c("name1","name2","name3","name"1),
              comment=c("comment 1","comment 2","comment 3","comment4"))

ui<-  sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(
            inputId="select_j",
            label="choose name",
            choices=c("name1","name2","name3")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          fluidRow(textOutput("texte")),
          fluidRow(textInput(
            inputId = "comment",
            label="Make a comment")),
          actionButton("submit", "Submit"))
    
)

server<-function(input,output){
  df_filter=reactive({df %>% subset(nom %in% input$select_j)})
  
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    new_line=c(input$select_j,input$comment)
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- new_line
    write.csv2(df,"save.csv")
  })
  
  output$texte <- renderText({ 
    input$submit
    nrow(df_filter())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution (maybe not the only one).

The `df` has to be set as a `reactiveVal` and then update when observe event

```
df<-data.frame(
    nom=c("name1","name2", "name3"),
    comment=c("comment 1", "comment 2", "comment 3")
)

ui<-sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(
            inputId="select_j",
            label="choose name",
            choices=c("name1","name2","name3")
        )
    ),
    mainPanel(
        fluidRow(textOutput("texte")),
        fluidRow(textInput(
            inputId="comment",
            label="Make a comment")
        ),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit"))
    )

    server<-function(input, output) {
        df_r=reactiveVal(df)
        df_filter=reactive({
            df_r() %>% subset(nom %in% input$select_j)
        })
  
        observeEvent(input$submit,{
            new_line=c(input$select_j, input$comment)
            new_df<-rbind(df_r(), new_line)
            df_r(new_df) #update the reactive value
            write.csv2(new_df, "save.csv")
        })
  
        output$texte <- renderText({ 
            input$submit
            nrow(df_filter())
        })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```